# Email to Salesforce Error from Outlook Web App

Tags: emailtosalesforce

People using Outlook for Web to BCC send email to Salesforce are getting the following error:

---

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:
Generating server: ex2013.crxxxxxnk.local
Receiving server: mx3-sjl.mta.salesforce.com (204.14.234.99)
emailtosalesforce@7-wntyeznygj3hxttjowv83yg4z0bhsb9n943504sslum4njwgj.j-1rxc4eai.na16.le.salesforce.com
Remote Server at mx3-sjl.mta.salesforce.com (204.14.234.99) returned '400 4.4.7 Message delayed'
3/26/2015 4:26:51 PM - Remote Server at mx3-sjl.mta.salesforce.com (204.14.234.99) returned '451 4.4.0 Primary target IP address responded with: "421 4.4.1 Connection timed out." Attempted failover to alternate host, but that did not succeed. Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts. The last endpoint attempted was 204.14.234.99:25'
```

---

They have authorized their OWA email address.
If they also authorize their personal email address and send mail from their personal account (not OWA) then they are successful in adding the email to the activity history.
Ideas?

Comment: Any solution for this yet?